# How to use if/else inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Basically I have a relatively complex piece of code in which has several arrays nested inside each other. I believe that what I'd like to do is not strictly possible:

```
$selector = true,
 $main_array = array(
  'general' = array(
   'another_array' = array(
    'option1' = array(
     'title' = 'Some Title',
     'type' = 'select',
       if ($selector == true) {
    'option2' = array(
     'title' = 'Some title',
     'type' = 'select',
     } else
    ...
```

I know that the above is not possible. I know that I could use ternary operator but it didn't work when I tried. I know that there better ways to solve this problem, but as far I can tell, all of them would involve me changing the whole structure (as there are many arrays nested inside each other) which I don't want to do, so my question is, is there a way around that I could use to make this conditional work without me changing the whole thing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are not actually attempting to assign arrays to string literals, so judiciously adding some '>'s

And yes, if I understand what you are looking for, it can be accomplished with a ternary operation, as follows:

```
$main_array = array(
 'general' => array(
  'another_array' => array(
   'option1' => array(
    'title' => 'Some Title',
    'type' => 'select',
   'option2' => (($selector == true) ?
    array(
     'title' => 'Some title',
     'type' => 'select',
    ) : 'It was false'
 )))));
```

Comment: That's great! I've tried using ternary operation before but I must have ben misusing it as I was getting an error all the time. Now it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're right: what you want to do isn't possible the way you want to do it. You'll have to restructure your code. You could push each element into the array individually, using `if` statements where necessary to determine what gets pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator. With the ternary operator, this:

```
if($selector == true){
    $foo = 'something'; 
} else {
    $foo = 'something else';
}
```

can become this:

```
$foo = ($selector == true) ? 'something' : 'something else';
```

Your example code would look something like this:

```
$selector = true;    
$main_array = array(
    'general' => array(
         'another_array' => array(
              'option1' => array(
                    'title' => 'Some Title',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'option2' => ($selector == true) ? array('title' = 'Some title','type' = 'select') : array('title' => 'Some other title', 'type' => 'Some other type')
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you heart is set on using if/else rather than a ternary you can work some of the results out a bit early.

```
       if ($selector == true) {
    $preset2 = array(
     'title' = 'Some title',
     'type' = 'select'
     );
    }
    else
    {
     $preset2 = array( ... );
    }

 $main_array = array(
  'general' = array(
   'another_array' = array(
    'option1' = array(
     'title' = 'Some Title',
     'type' = 'select' ),
    'option2' = $preset2,
```